# Back Slash N is not working in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have a very long string stored in a .plist file.
When i fetch the data and display it to a `UITextView` it shows an output like this.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to draw a line break every time a string parse `\n` but instead of this it show the `\n` itself as it is.

Comment: Why does the plist file have the characters \ and `n`? Put actual newlines in the plist file.

Answer (score 1):

While reading from the plist, the string is auto escaped. So you have to undo it.

```
let newText = oldText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
textView.text = newText
```